# Regex - start with “a” and involve one or more “b”s

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that finds strings that starts with an `a` and has one or more `b(s)` anywhere else in the string.

I know I have to start with `'^a` but I'm lost after that on how to get it to find b's anywhere else after that. I think the closest I got was `'^a.+.b+$'` which I randomly tried to see if it worked, but of course, it isn't right.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
, make your question [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for coding question which have to can be reproduced to help you.

Answer (score 6):

It's even a bit simpler:

```
^a.*b
```

You start with an `a`, follow it with 0 or more arbitrary characters, then a `b`. If all you want is at least 1 `b`, you don't need to explicitly match anything after you find the first `b`.

Your regular expression requires a string that

1. Starts with `a`,
2. followed by *1* or more arbitrary characters,
3. followed by *another* arbitrary character,
4. and ends with a string of 1 or more `b`s.

Note this precludes strings like

- `ab`, which is shorter than the minimum length of 4 required by your regex.
- `abasbbc`, which doesn't end with `b`

Comment: Good answer, but that last bullet point is off, `re.match(r'^a.+.b+$', 'abcb')` matches fine.

Comment: but then if you have a string such as "abccccc" it cuts off after the b, and wont display the c's (sorry if I wasn't clear on that) So I tried and `'^a.*b*$'` and it seems to work

Comment: @tjw By your regex you are saying `b` is no more mandatory. You need `^a.*b.*$`

Comment: Fixed the last bullet point. Since regular expressions aren't anchored to the end of the string by default, `.*$` isn't necessary at the end of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing chepner answer, if you want to find two `b` that are not necessary together, then you can use:

```
^a.*b.*b
```

If you want to find two `b` that must be separated, you can use:

```
^a.*b[^b]+b
```

Also, if you want to find two `b` like `bb` after `a`, then you can use

```
^a.*bb
```

And, if you want to find at least one `b`, then you can use:

```
^a.*b+
```

By the way, above regex will match start of sentence, if you want to match the whole sentence you can add `.*` at the end of the pattern, like:

```
^a.*b+.*
```

Comment: Second regex could be matched by first regex. Third regex doesn't need  a quantifier for `b`, forth either.

Comment: @revo, I know... OP question is kinda unclear. I'm just showing potential scenarios that complements chepner's

Comment: and I'm saying *if you want to find two `b` that are **not** together* is not true since `^a.*b.*b` matches `abb`.

Comment: @revo, ah didn't get you. So, you mean you want `^a.*b[^b]+b`. Let me clarify that statement, I meant to say two `b` that not necessary must be together but this is good to add it

Comment: I don't quite understand your wording. Anyway new update is better. +1